# Matrix Concatenation using Actionscript Matrix3D

Tags: actionscript, stage3d, agal

I want to get the properly rendered projection result from a Stage3D framework that presents something of a 'gray box' interface via its API.  It is gray rather than black because I can see this critical snippet of source code:

```
matrix3D.copyFrom (renderable.getRenderSceneTransform (camera));
matrix3D.append (viewProjection);
```

The projection rendering technique that perfectly suits my needs comes from a helpful tutorial that works directly with AGAL rather than any particular framework. Its comparable rendering logic snippet looks like this:

```
cube.mat.copyToMatrix3D (drawMatrix);
drawMatrix.prepend (worldToClip);
```

So, I believe the correct, general summary of what is going on here is that both pieces of code are setting up the proper combined matrix to be sent to the Vertex Shader where that matrix will be a parameter to the m44 AGAL operation.  The general description is that the combined matrix will take us from Object Local Space through Camera View Space to Screen or Clipping Space.

My problem can be summarized as arising from my ignorance of proper matrix operations.  I believe my failed attempt to merge the two environments arises precisely because the semantics of prepending one matrix to another is not, and is never intended to be, equivalent to appending that matrix to the other.  My request, then, can be summarized in this way.  Because I have no control over the calling sequence that the framework will issue, e.g., I must live with an append operation, I can only try to fix things on the side where I prepare the matrix which is to be appended.  That code is not black-boxed, but it is too complex for me to know how to change it so that it would meet the interface requirements posed by the framework.

Is there some sequence of inversions, transformations or other manuevers which would let me modify a viewProjection matrix that was designed to be prepended, so that it will turn out right when it is, instead, appended to the Object's World Space coordinates?

Comment: The framework you're using - is it away3d or the simple variant minimole? Perhaps you could also describe what you are trying to do...it sounds like you are doing something the framework does not provide built in facilities to do - which may suggest you are doing something incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, the framework to which I was trying to marry the Camera3D which Jackson Dunstan uses in one of his nice tutorial demonstrations was Away3d's Version 4.1. As I indicated in my reply, I did succeed in effected the necessary change by performing the transpose of a transpose operations. Thank you for following up.

Comment: I have also learned some information which may be helpful. The operations on the CPU side and the GPU side are brisk enough that there is no loss in FPS rate. And, I now understand that the reason the Dunstan camera is "different" is that he chose to implement a Right-Handed Camera/Lens Space rather than the Left-Handed one that most examples borrow from the com.adobe.utils.PerspectiveMatrix3D class. With that additional explanation, perhaps there are better suggestions as to how to modify/adapt between the two -- it seems not merely to be a matter of reversing the sign of the .z orientation.

Comment: No, it's not a trivial matter. I built a full 3D engine based on a left-handed coordinate system using mnimole and away3d for inspiration. There are some important functions which need to be modified for left-handed use, such as the lookAt command. Also, you will have to modify the camera/lens projection matrix - which requires a bit of math. I strongly recommend "Mathematics for 3D Game Programming and Computer Graphics" by Eric Lengyel. Chapter 4 has all the answers you need!

Answer (score 1):

I am providing an answer more out of desperation than sure understanding, and still hope I will receive a better answer from those more knowledgeable. From Dunn and Parberry's "3D Math Primer" I learned that "transposing the product of two matrices is the same as taking the product of their transposes in reverse order."

Without being able to understand how to enter text involving superscripts, I am not sure if I can reduce my approach to a helpful mathematical formulation, so I will invent a syntax using functional notation. The equivalency noted by Dunn and Parberry would be something like:

```
AB = transpose (B) x transpose (A)
```

That comes close to solving my problem, which problem, to restate, is really just a problem arising out of the fact that I cannot control the behavior of the internal matrix operations in the framework package. I can, however, perform appropriate matrix operations on either side of the workflow from local object coordinates to those required by the GPU Vertex Shader.

I have not completed the test of my solution, which requires the final step to be taken in the AGAL shader, but I have been able to confirm in AS3 that the last 'un-transform' does yield exactly the same combined raw data as the example from the author of the camera with the desired lens properties whose implementation involves prepending rather than appending.

```
BA = transpose (transpose (A) x transpose (B))
```

I have also not yet tested to see if these extra calculations are so processing intensive as to reduce my application frame rate beyond what is acceptable, but am pleased at least to be able to confirm that the computations yield the same result.